# How do I make a custom path using python and matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

For my study project, I need to write an algorithm that tries to find the best solution to fold a protein. In order to make interpretation easy I wat to make a visualisation using MatPlotLib, exactly like this:
[image]

I followed some examples on the internet and managed to come up with the following code:`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

protein = "PHPPHPHH"
coordinates = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 2), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 1), (1, 0)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
Path = mpath.Path
path_data = []



for i in range(len(coordinates)):
    if i == 0:
        path_data.append((Path.MOVETO, (coordinates[i])))
    else:
        path_data.append((Path.LINETO, (coordinates[i])))
print(path_data)


codes, verts = zip(*path_data)
path = mpath.Path(verts, codes)

# plot control points and connecting lines
x, y = zip(*path.vertices)
line, = ax.plot(x, y, 'go-', color='grey')


ax.grid()
ax.axis('equal')
plt.title('Visualisation')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig("Visualisation.png")`
```

Resulting in this visualisation:
[image]

My question is:
-How can I change the color of the dots corresponding to the amino acids(H or P) and add a corresponding legend?

- How do I draw the dotted lines in the case that two H amino acids lay next to eachother and can bond?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can call `ax.plot` as many times as you want. You also don't need to make a path object to extract out the x/y values.

Comment: Thanks Paul for your answer, but I'am fairly new to programming and don't really understand your answer:(

Comment: you need to provide more information "How do I draw the dotted lines in the case that two H amino acids lay next to each other and can bond?" doesn't really explain what you're trying to do. how are you depicting amino acids and how are they represented as data structures? what does bonding mean in the context of the visualization?